# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error message

Tags: php

I am trying to find the solution for the error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

From googling, I found that its about code error. So, I went to look at the line it is causing the error.

```
<?
$file = file_get_contents('js/book.js', true);
echo $file;
?>
```

This code used to work, however, after we cleaned the server, we are coming across this issue.

So what I tried

```
<?php 
$file = file_get_contents('js/book.js', true);
echo $file;
?>
```

and that causes a new error `HTTP ERROR 500`.

I am extremely confused on how php can even start as `<?` and not the usual way of `<?php`

Is there any point that I have to look out for?

Comment: What is the error message **in full**? What file and line of code does it refer to? What does _"clean the server"_ mean?

Comment: The reason for an HTTP 500 error will be logged in your web server's error log. What does that say?

Comment: @Phil It points to that above code that I pasted.

Comment: The error message **in full**, please. A screenshot may help convey the context better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason, it is because of my php version. Had to upgrade it. Also, had to change the php code of connecting to the database.